# Very slow start up after excute python file using pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have noticed a slow start up around 13 seconds after excute python file using pyinstaller,
I have read a lot of threads regarding the problem with not solid solution,
I tried with noupx.. as I rea might be the size problem ....however still slow,

Any suggestion ??

Comment: Antivirus program?

Comment: @KlausD.
You mean I have in my computer ??

Comment: Yes, your antivirus program may be scanning the file before executing it, and depending on how big the file is, it can create delays for starting the program.

Comment: @pigeonburger
I understand, but no way to solve such problem ??

Comment: Antivirus programs usually allow you to disable scanning specific files, so you can do that. You could also disable your antivirus altogether, but that will create other security risks.